# How to force HTTP to HTTPS with an exception?

Tags: linux, .htaccess, redirect, ssl, https

So I had to force all connections via HTTP to go to HTTPS on a specific folder (e.g. "public_html/folder1"). I found a tutorial somewhere and used the following in an .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} folder 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/folder/$1 [R,L]
```

Problem is, I have a folder inside that folder1 which should be allowed to be accessed via HTTP and not just HTTPS, how do I make an exception? (meaning, I want for instance folder1/subfolder1 to be allowed to be accessed via HTTP).

Thanks

Comment: Can I ask why you don't force https for everything ? It's more secure and allow you to activate HSTS on your domain, which is the only protection against man-in-the-middle attacks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/folder/((?!subfolder).*)$ 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/folder/$1 [R,L]
```

The pattern `^/folder/((?!subfolde).*)` matches the request uri string `/folder/.*` and it doesnt match when the string is `/folder/subfolder/.*` so the rule is not applied.

Comment: Thanks, that did it :)